# unable to source bash file from python shell script

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell, tcsh

Hello I am trying to source of file say check.setup from my pythons script.
Code

```
import os
os.system("source /fullpathhere/check.setup")
```

It says command not found. Surprisingly I can source the same file directly from the shell.
check.setup is csh file. It is sourcing other .csh files and setting few environment variable I saw few answers here but no one could possibly solve the problem.
PS: I tried to write bash file instead of python. I also tried using subprocess.Popen. Problem persists.
Aashish

Comment: I'm unsure of the likelyhood of this being correct (thus comment not answer), but I've heard that sometimes `source` is actually an alias for `.`. It might be worthwhile to see if `. /fullpathhere/check.setup` works as your command.

Comment: What is your default shell on your machine ? See that with `echo $SHELL` and test first this command on your `source /fullpath/check.setup` directly in your console to see the result.

Comment: Both source and . are built-in shell commands and not something you can execute like this. But even if you could, there would be no point, because os.system spawns a subshell: any env vars set in that subshell would immediately be lost when it exits as the command returns.

Comment: @ Delioth I tried {. /fullpathhere/check.setup). It does not work. Same error

Comment: @gkegoux its tcsh. Apologies but I dont understand your suggestion. you want me to write script using Tcsh? I tried bash it gives same result.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually I am doing some work on the shell which involves series of steps like sourcing some files then calling some other python script. So all I want is to write one script that I can execute rather than doing say 20 steps manually. So few steps involves sourcing some files as I have mentioned

Comment: There is **absolutely no benefit** to sourcing a shell script from a Python interpreter. To the extent that it's possible at all (by spawning a shell interpreter and telling that interpreter to source the script), it has all the negative effects that simply executing that script as a subprocess would have (such as the changes made by the script not persisting past the end of its execution).

Answer (score 0):

use popen

```
subprocess.Popen('source ./fullpathhere/check.setup', shell=True)
```

Comment: Hey I used Popen. (Sort of). from subprocess import call. then call('source ./fullpath/check.setup', shell= True). It didnt work. Same problem

Comment: `source` is a bashism; to work in POSIX sh, it needs to be `.`

Comment: though at that point there is **absolutely no benefit** of using either `source` or `.` over just `subprocess.Popen(['sh', './fullpathhere/check.setup'])` (substituting an alternate interpreter if one prefers) without any `shell` argument at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't tag your posting as *csh*, even though you explicitly mention csh in your question....

There is no executable namend *source* (you can verify it by typing `bin/which source`. Well, you pointed out by yourself, that this is supposed to be done by *csh*, but how should Python know that it needs to invoke csh, if you don't tell it?

I don't have a csh on my system, but if I remember right from the time a couple of decades ago, where I indeed used csh for programming, you can do something like

```
os.system("csh -c fullpathhere/check.setup")
```

Actually, I would also specify the -f flag for skipping .cshrc, unless you really need that to be sourced as well.

Comment: Given how `system()` is implemented, you're telling the OP to run `sh -c "csh -c fullpathhere/check.setup"`. That's... really quite silly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for tag. I have added now. I couldnt exactly find cshell. I tried doing that but problem is I dont have permission to access the file. I am not even authorized to give permission using chmod. So i made another csh file from python script sourced my check.setup from that. I could give permission to file I made from python script as I created it. I then executed my csh file from python

Comment: @Charles Duffy: Isn't Python clever enough to omit the `sh` process in this case (as Perl would do in this case)? But even if an additional POSIX shell process is created to run the C-Shell, I don't consider it that bad (given the convenience of using `os.system`) .

Comment: The biggest costs are to correctness, not convenience. Invoking a shell means your data needs to be escaped to be correctly parsed; invoking two shells means it needs to be escaped twice. And invoking a shell at all means you're vulnerable to initialization-time issues such as shellshock. And no, Python (thankfully!) doesn't try to be clever and do things behind the programmer's back.

Comment: Actuall, the escaping itself is maybe not the problem: You only escape ones (for the immediately calling shell, i.e. `sh`), unless your "lower" shell has it's own set of very different escaping mechanism, in which case indeed things get hairy. As for correctness, I see the bigger risk in that (AFIK) it is not precisely specified which shell the "implicitly called" one is. OTOH, people using `os.system` do it exactly because they want the shell to fiddle with their command line (example: wildcard expansion), and my solution is close to the OP's code. I understand your point, though.

Comment: @user1934428, you can't only escape once without risking shell injection attacks if you're handling untrusted data. Let's say you're trying to pass a file named `/uploads/$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'`, or `/uploads/' '/etc/passwd` (the latter as created by `mkdir $'\' \''`, the former as created by `touch $'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\'`) -- if you ran `system("sh -c '/run/my/script " + filename + "'")` you'd have a bad day with either, despite having a single layer of explicit quoting via the literal single-quotes in the text (since the literal single quotes in the filenames end them).